# PKI security for .net application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, x509certificate, pki

I want to use PKI public and private encryption for authentication to allow for a more streamlined and secure application access control system. Any help in the generation of certificate and authentication will be useful. 
One more question, can i use System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates class for the same?

Answer (score -2):

Do you need to reinvent the wheel, all the above are possible with the existing framework IIS/ASP.NET/WCF.

Comment: Can you give me a link where i can find an example for the same